# require.js - including jquery and using require-jquery.js

Tags: requirejs

I am having a lot of trouble getting `jQuery` to load properly with `require.js`, despite seeing hundreds of examples and samples. You can actually read more about my frustrations in a completely different question, seen here ...

## [25126564](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126564/requirejs-only-seems-to-work-half-the-time)

My question here is a bit related, but on the `require.js` website, there is a comment at the bottom of this page: [Using requirejs with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html)

> Previously, we've been pointing to an example using a special
>   require-jquery file, which consisted of require.js and jQuery
>   concatenated. This is no longer the recommended way to use jQuery with
>   require.js, but if you're looking for the (no longer maintained)
>   example, you can find require-jquery here.

My major question is **why is this not recommended anymore**? I tried it out on my own and this has been the only way I have been able to reproduce consistent results of loading `jquery` alongside `requirejs`. Why was this method dropped? What is the 'correct' way of doing it? As you can see in my other question, I've got working code, but it only works **literally** half the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because:

1. jQuery supports AMD out of the box: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#modulename
2. More generally, libraries that are not AMD-ready can be turned into an AMD module by using the `shim` configuration, no need to wrap the original module or edit original library distribution.